# Azure Functions Route binding with unknown URL

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to construct the function.json file where the url has a custom ending that we don't know. This customer ending may include forward slashes so I can't be guaranteed this will be one parameter. My current code :

```
    {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "authLevel": "function",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",      
        "route": "{param1}/customer/{param2}/{restOfUrl}",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
          "get"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "res"
      }
    ],
    "scriptFile": "../dist/src/handlers/myScript.js"
  }
```

this works fine when for example the url is:

```
...123/customer/456/rest-of-url
```

however if the rest of the url contains forward slashes eg:

```
...123/customer/456/rest/of/url
```

I get a 404 not found.

How do I correctly define the route if the url is unknown and will likely include forward slashes / ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying the suggested solution I discovered [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) doc in Azure documentation. The solution was to * the remaining parameter which returns the remainder of the path as a string. The change looks as so :

```
 "route": "{param1}/customer/{param2}/{*restOfUrl}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an appsetting to disable the url encoding so that it will match a full path. By default slashes are encoded as `%2F`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azure_function_proxy_backend_url_decode_slashes

Comment: Thanks for this however when looking at the documentation I read this - "When AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_BACKEND_URL_DECODE_SLASHES is set to true, the URL example.com/api%2ftest resolves to example.com/api/test. By default, the URL remains unchanged as example.com/test%2fapi"

So by default the url is remaining unchanged. The only way I can get it to successfully execute the function is if the url is 

...123/customer/456/rest%2Fof%2Furl 

and the function root  expects

{param1}/customer/{customerId}/{restOfUrl}

restOfUrl therefore gets rest%2Fof%2Furl and I do a character switch.